# Admob RewardedVideo via Firebase

Tags: ios, swift, admob, rewardedvideoad

i know this kind of question has been asked a lot but i've tried everything out there and cannot find what is going on.

I'm not using mediation and I have no troubles showing Interstitial. Here is my configuration:

```
class MainContainerViewController: UIViewController, GADInterstitialDelegate, GADRewardBasedVideoAdDelegate {

    var rewardBasedVideo: GADRewardBasedVideoAd?

    override func viewDidLoad() {

        super.viewDidLoad()

        ...

        rewardBasedVideo = GADRewardBasedVideoAd.sharedInstance()
        rewardBasedVideo?.delegate = self
        let request = GADRequest()
        request.testDevices = ["b8d6d8f423b67dc1855d953466503d0d"]
        rewardBasedVideo?.load(request, withAdUnitID: "ca-app-pub-3872067921404234/2000937302")
    }

    func rewardBasedVideoAd(_ rewardBasedVideoAd: GADRewardBasedVideoAd, didFailToLoadWithError error: Error) {

        NSLog("didFailToLoad \(error.localizedDescription)")
    }
}
```

I've tried loading AdUnitID for testing with no success and the log everytime i tried to load a new rewarded video is showing:

```
<Google> Cannot find an ad network adapter with the name(s): com.google.DummyAdapter. Remember to link all required ad network adapters and SDKs, and set -ObjC in the 'Other Linker Flags' setting of your build target.
didFailToLoad No ad returned from any ad server.
```

Any help would be great. Thanks in advance,

//EDIT

Could it be related with device size? I've tested on simulator and it works fine but on iPhone 7plus the result is the one showed above. Anyone can confirm this???

Comment: Did you find the issue?

Comment: Hi @SamBing not sure of what's happening but i've been able to receive rewarded ads in every device i've tried except from iPhone 7 plus... not sure if this could be the reason, but it seems so...

Comment: I had the issue with the test ad unit id, i created my own and all is working well now. Testing mainly on the iPhone 7 Plus and works fine, so i'm not sure.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to install the Adapter SDK, Firebase SDK correctly and link them correctly in the BuildPhases -> Link Binary with Libraries. Also add the search paths as mentioned in the docs. The error means that either there is no ad to display or you're receiving a faulty Ad. I checked your Ad Unit ID with [sample apps](https://github.com/googleads/googleads-mobile-ios-examples) and everything works fine. Check your implementation and Pod installation again.